# Can we use javascript to tell whether the source of a html5 video element loaded correctly?

Tags: javascript, html, html5-video

I have a page with a `<video>` tag that can have its `src` attribute altered depending on what video link a user selects. This is the code below:

**HTML**

```
 <video width="944" height="440" id="video" src="[url to video]" controls=""></video>
```

**javascript**

```
...
obj = //link selector

try{                   
      $("#video").prop("src","video/"+$(obj).data("video"));
   }catch(err){

   }
```

Now i have a strange case where on second call of this code, the video doesnt work correctly in IE. I have decided therefore to add in a catch statement to handle such scenarios and load the video in a different method which seems to work (that is, by completely removing the video tag and re-adding it in with the new src attribute). Issue is that i cannot seem to catch the video error that it generates. I believe this is because the call is asynchronous. (for reference, the error in question is `MEDIA12899: AUDIO/VIDEO: Unknown MIME type.`. The strange thing is that as i stated earlier, the video loads correctly the first time, not the second time).

Anyone know how i can determine if we can detect whether a video loaded properly?

Comment: I could be getting old but I thought you needed ```<source />``` elements as children for the ```video``` tag?

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/cv9qj9dr/2/ you can use autoplay media api or without js checkout jsfiddle link

Answer (score 1):

Yes – you can use the various [media events](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/Events/Media_events) provided on a `<video>` element.

For example:

```
$('a.your.link.here').on('click', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();

  $('#video')
    .attr('src', 'video/' + $(this).data('video'))
    .off('error')
    .off('canplay')
    .on('error', function() {
      alert('oh noes, an error!');
    })
    .on('canplay', function() {
      alert('can play!');
    });
});
```

This code will do the following when an anchor with the class `your link here` is clicked:

- Update your `<video>` element's `src` attribute
- Remove any existing event handlers on the `<video>` element
- Bind two event handlers on the `<video>` element – one that pops up an `alert` when there's an error, and one that pops up an `alert` when the video is ready to play.

Answer (score 1):

> *"Anyone know how i can determine if we can detect whether a video loaded properly?"*

While it is nice to know how to detect whether a video is loaded or not, I believe that the problems you have clearly stated already should be addressed instead. If you identified the issues at hand, then knowing how to detect a properly loaded video is pointless ATM. **[See XY Problem](http://xyproblem.info/)**

---

> **Problem 1** *"The strange thing is that as I stated earlier, the video loads correctly the first time, **not the second time**"*

When a `<video>` tag is loaded during a pageload, it loads the url value of the `src` attribute just like any other **[replaced element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Replaced_element)** such as an `<img>` or `<iframe>`. When changing a `src` attribute's value, we may need to load it before it can be played. The following demo has a `<video>` tag and a playlist for demonstrating how `src` changing works with the [**`.load()` method**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLMediaElement#Methods).

**Possible Solution:** `load()` method.

---

> **Problem 2** *"`MEDIA12899: AUDIO/VIDEO: Unknown MIME type`"*

You may have an incompatibility issue with the filetype of the video files. I couldn't tell for certain because you provided no url or what type of video is being used.

**Possible Solution:** Add a **[`<source>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/source)** tag for an MP4 and a `<source>` tag for a duplicate file encoded as a WebM video.

**Details commented in Demo**

#### Demo

```js
// Reference the <video> tag
var vid = document.getElementById('vid0');

// Reference the first <source> tag
var srcA = document.getElementById('src0');

// Reference the second <source> tag
var srcB = document.getElementById('src1');

// Collect all <a> into a NodeList
var lnx = document.links;

/* Iterate through the NodeList and regeister each <a> on click
|| event.
|| When click occurs, callback function switchSRC is invoked
*/
for (let i = 0; i < lnx.length; i++) {
  lnx[i].onclick = switchSRC;
}

// Pass the Event Object 
function switchSRC(e) {

  // Prevent <a> from jumping to location of href
  e.preventDefault();

  // Set the src of the first <source> to href of clicked <a>
  srcA.src = e.target.href;

  // Set the src of the second <source> to data-webm of clicked <a>
  srcB.src = 'https://storage04.dropshots.com/' + e.target.getAttribute('data-webm');

  /* Problem 1 - load() Method
  || Call load() method if there is a change in src and 
  || fails to load. This isn't always neccessary but it
  || never hurts to have it just in case.
  */
  vid.load();

  // Call play() method
  vid.play();
}
```

```css
body {
  font: 400 20px/1.2 Consolas;
}

video,
ol {
  margin: 0;
  display: inline-block;
  float: left;
}
```

```html
<!--Problem 2 - MIME Type Error
-The src attribute normally in the <video> tag has been replaced by 2 <source> tags.
-The optimal video MIME types can be narrowed down to two types: video/mp4 and video/webm.
-Have a copy of each MP4 encoded as a WebM video file and set the src of each <source> tag accordingly. Set the type attribute to 
video/mp4 and video/webm.
-NOTE: in this demo the webm file extension is *.mp4. DO NOT DO THIS. They are webm files with *.mp4 extensions because the host doesn't recognize webm files.
-->

<video id='vid0' width='320' controls>
  <source id='src0' src='https://storage04.dropshots.com/photos6000/photos/1381926/20170326/005609.mp4' type='video/mp4'>
  <source id='src1' src='https://storage04.dropshots.com/photos7000/photos/1381926/20180214/041157.mp4' type='video/webm'>
</video>

<ol>
  <li>
    <a href='https://storage04.dropshots.com/photos6000/photos/1381926/20170326/005609.mp4' data-webm='photos7000/photos/1381926/20180214/041157.mp4'>leader00</a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href='https://storage04.dropshots.com/photos6000/photos/1381926/20170326/005610.mp4' data-webm='photos7000/photos/1381926/20180214/041153.mp4'>leader01</a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href='https://storage04.dropshots.com/photos6000/photos/1381926/20170326/005611.mp4' data-webm='photos7000/photos/1381926/20180214/041154.mp4'>leader02</a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href='https://storage04.dropshots.com/photos6000/photos/1381926/20170326/005612.mp4' data-webm='https://storage04.dropshots.com/photos7000/photos/1381926/20180214/041156.mp4'>leader03</a>
  </li>
</ol>
```